Correspondence between extender and HOD-like mice
Given a least-branch mouse $M$, must there be a matching pure-extender mouse $N$ definable in $M$?
"matching" means having the same strength and in a sense matching extender positions, and an answer should explain what kind of matching we get.  Definability should ordinarily be first-order, but there might be edge cases.  As the question may be hard, I am also interested in a representative special case.
Let $M^\#$ and $N^\#$ be the least-branch (or HOD-like) and pure extender mice (respectively) for $\text{AD}_ℝ + \text{DC}$.  Is $N$ definable in $M$, and if so how?
If I understand correctly:
    $M$ is the minimal iterable inner model with $κ$ Woodin cardinals, with supremum $λ_M$, where $κ$ is the least measurable in $M$, and with the model self-iterable below $λ_M$.  It is the minimal inner model elementarily embeddable into HOD of an inner model of $\text{AD}_ℝ + \text{DC}$ containing all the reals.  (Technically, $M|λ_M$ rather than $M$ is least-branch.)
    $N$ is the minimal iterable inner model with a limit $λ_N$ of Woodin cardinals and of $λ_N$-many $<λ_N$-strong cardinals.  In $N$, HOD of the derived model at $λ_N$ is an iterate of $M$ (and perhaps the minimal iterate of $M$ definable in $N$), and in $N^\#$ we can take the theory of the indiscernibles of an iterate of $M$ to erase the iteration and get $M^\#$.
I suspect that:
- $M$ and $N$ agree below their least Woodin cardinal.
- The $1+α$th Woodin cardinal ($α=0$ for the least Woodin) of $M$ is the least Woodin above $α$ $<λ_N$ strong cardinals of $N$.  Its cardinal successor in $M$ is the next $<λ_N$-strong cardinal in $N$, and with further cardinals in $N$ up to the next Woodin preserved.
- $K^{M|λ_M} = N|λ_M$, where $K$ is extender-based (rather than strategic) core model (analogously to the Varsovian models papers).
- $L_1(M|λ_M)$ likely corresponds to $N|λ_N$ or $L_1(N|λ_N)$.
If true, this means that a single step in $M$ skips over many Woodins and $<λ_N$-strongs in $N$, but how?  I think the difference is the ability of $M$ to use the measure on $κ$ to generate iteration strategies for more Woodin cardinals.
I use $L_1$ in the above because quantification over sets of reals of the derived model is (using $\text{AD}_ℝ$) is first order over $M|λ_M$ and $N|λ_N$.  Note that there are four related inner models of $\text{AD}_ℝ + \text{DC}$ here (plus non-uniqueness except in the last one due to genericity):  One with $Θ=λ_M$ and $\mathrm{HOD}=M$, one with $ω_1=λ_M$ (derived model for $M$), one with $ω_1=λ_N$ (derived model for $N$), and one containing all the reals (based on $ℝ$ genericity iteration using $M$ or $N$).
Additional correspondences:
- For countable $α$, the minimal inner model of AD + $Θ=θ_α$ containing all the reals corresponds to having $α$ $<λ_N$-strong cardinals in $N$ (with $λ_N$ still a limit of Woodins), and for limit $α$, $α$ Woodin cardinals in $M$.
- Requiring a model of $\text{AD}_ℝ$ to satisfy "all sets of reals are uB" should correspond to using strong rather than $<λ_N$-strong cardinals in $N$, and requiring self-iterability above $λ_M$ in $M$ (link).  The iterate of $M$ from the derived model in $N$ (with witnesses for sets of reals being uB) is plausibly also the generic HOD of $N$.
- For $M$ with $≥κ$ Woodins (where $κ$ is the least measurable in $M$), plausibly the $κ+α$-th Woodin in $M$ ($α<κ$) is the least Woodin above $1+α$ hyperstrongs in $V_λ^N$ (with lower Woodins in $M$ as before).
Converting extender mice to least-branch
I am also interested in the reverse question, that is when does an extender mouse $P$ have a matching least-branch mouse $Q$.  When it does, I suspect that an iterate of $Q$ is definable in $P$, at least assuming sufficient closure.  One can think of a least-branch mouse as an extender mouse with appropriate extenders aligned (hence less freedom in moving extenders), together with the alignment information, and iteration can do the alignment.
Plausibly, extender and least-branch hierarchy (below long extenders) give the same sequence of Turing degrees.  However, for every least-branch mouse $Q$, $δ<λ<κ$, $δ$ Woodin in $Q|λ$, and $κ$ a cardinal in $Q$, $Q|κ$ is closed under the operator corresponding to the portion of $Q|λ$ above $δ$.  Thus, least-branch mice require much higher degree of closure under operators corresponding to their initial segments.  On the other hand, plausibly, for every extender mouse satisfying Zermelo set theory, its generic HOD equals its mantle and is (the universe of) a least-branch mouse.

Correction:  The derived model for $M$ does not satisfy $\text{AD}_ℝ + \text{DC}$; one needs to do other constructions there.
